# Is there a way to provide additional data to Notion's OAuth flow?

Tags: go, telegram-bot, notion-api, telegram-webhook

I am building a Telegram bot (webhook implemented) to interact with Notion API. I need to link Telegram and Notion users between each other.

My Authorization URL from Notion's integration page looks like this:

```
https://api.notion.com/v1/oauth/authorize?client_id=123&response_type=code&owner=user&redirect_uri=https://de86-171-5-224-214.ngrok-free.app/notion/oauth/callback
```

Take a look at `redirect_uri` query param. I need something like `redirect_uri=https://de86-171-5-224-214.ngrok-free.app/notion/oauth/callback?extra_data=test`

When I try to pass any extra params to `redirect_uri`, it does not affect at all. After redirect to my callback endpoint, Notion pass the same params `code=123&state=` without customization. Is there a way to do so? Or maybe some hacks?

I am using Golang to build a bot.

Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Notion does allow to set `state` query parameter. Also for me the problem was "?" symbol in the `redirect_uri`.

Before fix:

```
redirect_uri=https://de86-171-5-224-214.ngrok-free.app/notion/oauth/callback?extra_data=test
```

After fix:

```
redirect_uri=https://de86-171-5-224-214.ngrok-free.app/notion/oauth/callback&state=test
```